# magento - User share/restrict per website

Tags: magento

I have three websites configured with Share Customer Accounts = Global.

I need a new website that has to be restricted to a few users. Is there any way I can manage this via a single magento instalation? The closest I can think of is using a .htaccess with something like this:

```
<files "filename.cgi">
AuthUserFile /home/pathto/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secret Place"
require valid-user
</files>
```

But where would I put it so that it would be “activated” only when visiting that specific website? I’m hoping there’s a better way. I've found a couple of extensions that should do the trick, but I'm not sure if the latest magento versions have this functionality.

The purpose of the new website/store is to simply allow for different prices for the same products, so if there’s anything I’m missing, please tell me.

I'm using magento 1.6.